# Origin of "of course"?

Tags: etymology

What is the origin of confirmative phrase "of course"? I assume it has something to do with sailing maybe?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Seems you are right

http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=course

> Phrase of course is attested from
>   1540s; lit. "of the ordinary course;"
>   earlier in same sense was bi cours
>   (c.1300).

Comment: I see nothing in that entry which mentions sailing or navigation. In the OED meanings of "course" to do with navigation are attested back to 1553, but "of course" in its modern sense a few years earlier.

Comment: @Colin Okeee, flowing of a river then....

Answer (score 4):

The NOAD reports that the origin of *course* is Middle English: from Old French *cours*, from Latin *cursus*, from *curs-* (run), from the verb *currere*.

(See also the definition of [*course*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/course) given by *Oxford Living Dictionaries*.)